# Android 10 udp brodcast not receive

Tags: udp, broadcast, android-10.0

Hi i use udp socket in android to find device and change their network parameter, example: change ip address of device.

In previous android my code works well and it is able to receive packet from different subnet example:
my ip is 192.168.43.5 and i send packet to 255.255.255.255 port 8888
device ip is 192.168.1.45 and send responce to 255.255.255.255 8889

why in android 10 i receive udp packet only if the device have the same subnet of my phone (ex if device ip = 192.168.43.45 works else if device ip = 192.168.1.45 not works)?

Comment: Any updates to this?